# MySQL: “Too many connections” in opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: opencart2.x

I recently installed opencart 2.0.3.1. Since I have installed opencart I get the below error

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (08004/1040): Too many connections     in /home/burhanie/public_html/store/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Error: Could not make a database link (1040) Too many connections in /home/burhanie/public_html/store/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli::close() [mysqli.close]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/burhanie/public_html/store/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 58

Below is the opencart code from file mysqli.php

```
public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port = '3306') {
    $this->link = new \mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port);

    if ($this->link->connect_error) {
        trigger_error('Error: Could not make a database link (' . $this->link->connect_errno . ') ' . $this->link->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $this->link->set_charset("utf8");
    $this->link->query("SET SQL_MODE = ''");
}
```

Below is the screen shot of phpmyadmin advisor. which states opencart is using too many connection. This seems to be a bug

[image]

Comment: Are you opening persistent connections? MySQLi should recycle connections that are no longer used. Are you closing connections that you have opened? Are you handling high levels of traffic - how many req/sec do you get?

Comment: I have not made any change to code after opencart installation. I am the only user using the site as I just started uploading the product.

Comment: Have you [researched the problem](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Too+many+connections%22+in+opencart+2)?

Comment: I researched but unable to succeed in resolved the error. This is no answer on google for this error with opencart. This error comes frequently while surfing the site